# What does the term TU stand for in a C# generic?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I see this occasionally in generic methods for the return type, e.g.

```
public async Task<TU> ResolveAsync<T, TU>(T context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I'm just curious as to what it stands for. All Google gave me was 'translation unit' but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: The `T` stands for "Type parameter" by convention.  The U is just U.  It doesn't mean anything.  It's nothing more than a placeholder token for a type parameter.

Comment: `TU` is just an identifier. You could put `KPZQpfxSeUzI` there if you wanted.

Comment: Type parameters, by convention, generally start with a `T`, but they don't have to.  There's no deeper meaning here.  It's not an initialism or abbreviation.

Comment: @Amy - I think it is confusing for the OP to suggest that `T` stands for "Type parameter". It's true that `T` often used to represent a generic type, but to say it stands for something gives it more meaning than it is worth.

Comment: @Enigmativity True, that isn't what I was meaning to communicate.  We prefix some identifiers with a letter to indicate their purpose.  It's too late to edit that comment though.

Answer (score 1):

The `TU` likely means nothing. Type parameters are like function parameters and have identifier / name. Just like function parameters they cannot have the same name which is why the declaration is not `ResolveAsync<T, T>`. `T` is common practise for parameter of any *T*ype. I am unsure of the library & context of your function but I am sure the `TU` likely means nothing and the `U` is just added to prevent using the same identifier.

You could think about it in terms of a  add function which might have the declaration `int add(int a, int b)` here `a` and `b` don't mean anything but are used to refer to two different parameters. If it doesn't have a precise identifier or generic constraints it probably isn't important of the name of the type parameter.

I would have a look at the function documentation on *learn.microsoft.com* or if you go to the declaration have a look at the docstring / xml comments as it may say something under `<typeparam>`.